# How to transmit USB gamepad over Bluetooth?

Tags: windows, usb, android, bluetooth, logitech-gamepad

So I have some games on my phone that support Bluetooth gamepads.
However the only gamepad I have, unfortunately doesn't have bluetooth but connects via USB.
**If it matters:** I'm using Windows 10, and an Android phone.

I did my reasearch and "Across" won't work as I actually tried it out, and it turns out [they don't support gamepads](https://community.acrosscenter.com/index.php?threads/is-it-possible-to-use-a-gamepad-controller.352/). Also I don't want to modify my USB controller and actually turn it into a bluetooth controller. Also I did look into `usb to micro usb converter` and I decided i **could** but would ask here first in case there is some program I can install or some fancy trick.

Is there a way I can take the USB of the gamepad, plug it into my computer, and send those inputs over bluetooth to my phone?

Comment: Besides this creating massive amounts of input lack, it will be very inconsistent if you can get it to work at all. Not even sure what is going to be required to make it work. Seriously,  you can get really good bluetooth gamepads from aliexpress for about 15 USD. Do yourself a favor and just buy one that works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go for a fun project you need a bluetooth capable MCU (10$) like the esp32 and some time and skill to get it running smoothly. Latency is not a topic with BLE once setup properly.
 If you just want to reuse "old" controllers forget it its. You get 15 to 20$ BLE gamepads with european/american online seller like A****n marketplace.
If you [want to read a how to](https://www.instructables.com/id/Make-Your-Old-Joystick-Bluetooth/) (there are better and easier (without soldering) around, but just to give you an idea about the time to spend..